# как на electron js сделать вкладки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Я делаю обертку для сайта на electron js через

```
const site_first = "https://github.com"
const site_second = "https://www.electronjs.org/"
const site_third = "https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/"
const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 800 })
win.loadURL(site_first)
```

как сделать между ними переключение через похожий интерфейс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я видел способ через [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs-with-dropdowns), но он только для html что мне не подходит.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-tabs

Comment: @AlexanderChernin огромное вам спасибо